# Combine index and columns and keep value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame as below

```
    A   B   C   
1   1   2   3    
2   4   2   5
```

And I want to combine index and column into a new index while keeping the value from the previous column + index as below

```
    Value
1A  1  
1B  2
1C  3
2A  4
2B  2
2C  5
```

I know I can iterate through it with `df.iterrows()` and create a new DataFrame from that, but I'm working with a huge dataset and it is too inefficient. Dataset is tens of millions of observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with list comprehension:

```
df = df.stack().to_frame('Value')
df.index = [f'{a}{b}' for a, b in df.index]
print (df)
    Value
1A      1
1B      2
1C      3
2A      4
2B      2
2C      5
```

Or use numpy solution with `ravel`:

```
c = np.tile(df.columns, len(df))
i = np.repeat(df.index, len(df.columns))

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': df.to_numpy().ravel()}, index=[f'{a}{b}' for a, b in zip(i, c)])
print (df)
    value
1A      1
1B      2
1C      3
2A      4
2B      2
2C      5
```